# Jest throws TypeError: (0 , _module.myFunction) is not a function, testing exported functions (non default) with Jest

Tags: typescript, jestjs, create-react-app

So I'm using Jest, Typescript and Create-react-app

I have this test:

```
import { defaultHeaders } from './http';

describe('http tests', () => {
  test('defaultHeaders()', () => {
    const headers = defaultHeaders(undefined);
    expect(headers).toEqual({ foo: 2 });
  });
});
```

The code is in same subdir in file `http.ts` and looks like this:

```
export function defaultHeaders(headers?: FetchHeaders): FetchHeaders {
  return { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' };
}
```

When I run my jest tests it throws:

```
TypeError: (0 , _http.defaultHeaders) is not a function
```

The weird part is that all other tests that are wrapped in a default function or const do work.

**Is there any way to test non default exported functions with Jest?**

### update:

- also tried converting defaultHeaders into an arrow function and that didn't help.
- and tried changing import as: `import * as http from './http'` that still makes it throw same error

Comment: There are no good reasons for this to happen, unless you redefined `defaultHeaders` export in the same file. A common case for an export to appear undefined is circular dependency but the code you posted doesn't suggest that. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Debug what's imported with `import * as http from './http'` and `import http from './http'`, it's only possible on your side. Also try `const { defaultHeaders } = require('./http')` and `const { defaultHeaders } = require('./http').default`. These attempts cover possibilities with incorrect TS module interoperation.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## Update with Answer

So the issue was that in `src/setupTest.ts` I included a mock of the module without the function I was trying to test therefore it was undefined.

```
// mock our fetch wrapper to avoid doing http calls in tests
jest.mock('utilities/http/http', () => ({
  // NO defaultHeaders() function mocked that was the problem 
  getRequest: function () {
    return {
      json: {},
      status: 200,
    };
  },
  postRequest: function () {
    return {
      json: {},
      status: 200,
    };
  },
  request: function () {
    return {
      json: {},
      status: 200,
    };
  },
}));
```

If I remove the mocked from setupTest.ts then I can unit test it.

Comment: Agreed. Check your test-setup.ts and make sure you didn't mistakingly mock something that shouldn't have been mocked.

Comment: Great! Thank you so much! I spent hours solving the problem. It turned out in setupTests the module was mocked just for one function without requiring the actual of others

Comment: Thanks! Obvious now I think of it but you saved me a bunch of time.

Answer (score 1):

When mocking with a jest.fn like this it also causes the problem:

```
const doThing = jest.fn();
jest.mock(
  '@/myfile',
  () => {
    return {
      doThing // Having a mock here - also causes the error.
    };
  },
  { virtual: true },
);
```

**FIX**

```
const JESTdoThing = jest.fn();
jest.mock(
  '@/myfile',
  () => {
    return {
      doThing: (x, y, z) => JESTdoThing(x, y, z)
    };
  },
  { virtual: true },
);

it('should run JESTdoThing', ()=> {
  thingWhichRunsDoThing();
  expect(JESTdoThing).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was on the path. I was testing a file named 'index.js' and I gave for granted that I didn't need to include it in the path when I was importing the function. I was wrong.

Wrong code:

```
import { myFunction } from '../my/path
```

Right code:

```
import { myFunction } from '../my/path/index.js
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had the same error when I forgot to desctructure my function when importing it in to my Jest test file.

Incorrect:
`import countScoresForPart2Strategy from "./countScoresForPart2Strategy";`

Correct:
`import { countScoresForPart2Strategy } from "./countScoresForPart2Strategy";`