# Custom function undefined when running jest -react native

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

I am writing test for a component where I am using a custom function that I wrote. That function is used in an error message as shown below

```
export const ERROR_MESSAGES = {
  ENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS_IN_APP_SETTINGS: `Please enable the notifications for ${getBrandName()} in the device settings`,
};
```

And this is the import of the function

```
import { getBrandName } from "@utils/CommonUtils";
```

Here **@utils => src/utils/**. It is a path alias.

But when I run the test I get this error

```
TypeError: (0 , _CommonUtils.getBrandName) is not a function

      13 |
      14 | export const ERROR_MESSAGES = {
    > 15 |   ENABLE_NOTIFICATIONS_IN_APP_SETTINGS: `Please enable the notifications for ${getBrandName()} in the device settings`,
         |                                                                                            ^
      16 | };
```

I searched for the issue and came across this article [Jest throws TypeError: (0 , _module.myFunction) is not a function, testing exported functions (non default) with Jest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63853794/jest-throws-typeerror-0-module-myfunction-is-not-a-function-testing-expor)

I checked but I am not mocking that file or function. Any help would be appreciated.

```
export const getBrandName = () => {
  return "Affluent";
};
```